# "Bad substitution" when submitting spark job to yarn-cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am doing a smoke test against a yarn cluster using `yarn-cluster` as the master with the `SparkPi` example program.  Here is the command line:

```
  $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster 
 --executor-memory 8G --executor-cores 240 --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
```

examples/target/scala-2.11/spark-examples-1.4.1-hadoop2.7.1.jar

The yarn accepts the job but then complains about a **"bad substitution"**.  Maybe it is on the `hdp.version` ??

```
15/09/01 21:54:05 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1441066518301_0013 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/09/01 21:54:05 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1441144443866
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://yarnmaster-8245.lvs01.dev.ebayc3.com:8088/proxy/application_1441066518301_0013/
     user: stack
15/09/01 21:54:06 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1441066518301_0013 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/09/01 21:54:10 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1441066518301_0013 (state: FAILED)
15/09/01 21:54:10 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1441066518301_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1441066518301_0013_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://yarnmaster-8245.lvs01.dev.ebayc3.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1441066518301_0013Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e03_1441066518301_0013_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /mnt/yarn/nm/local/usercache/stack/appcache/
application_1441066518301_0013/container_e03_1441066518301_0013_02_000001/
launch_container.sh: line 24: $PWD:$PWD/__hadoop_conf__:$PWD/__spark__.jar:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:
/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*::$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:
/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:
/etc/hadoop/conf/secure: bad substitution

Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /mnt/yarn/nm/local/usercache/stack/appcache/application_1441066518301_0013/container_e03_1441066518301_0013_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 24: $PWD:$PWD/__hadoop_conf__:$PWD/__spark__.jar:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure: bad substitution

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Of note here is:

```
/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:
/etc/hadoop/conf/secure: bad substitution
```

The "sh" is linked to bash:

```
$ ll /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep  1 05:48 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I guess your `/bin/sh` is dash, not bash. This could probably be the problem. See `man sh` to double check.

Comment: @xuhdev  No i only use bash to maintain compatibility.

Comment: I had the same problem, added the right hdp version in spark-defaults.conf, but the error remains. Following the path /usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/ on the cluster, I found no hadoop-lzo-.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar exists...?!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is caused by `hdp.version` not getting substituted correctly. You have to set `hdp.version` in the file `java-opts` under `$SPARK_HOME/conf`.

And you have to set

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=XXX 
spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=XXX
```

in `spark-defaults.conf` under `$SPARK_HOME/conf` where XXX is the version of hdp.

Comment: Do you need to restart something for those configurations to set in?

Comment: I added this in the node. but still gets the same error

Answer (score 13):

If you are using spark with hdp, then you have to do the following things:

Add these entries in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=2.2.0.0-2041 (your installed HDP version)

spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=2.2.0.0-2041 (your installed HDP version)
```

Create a file called `java-opts` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and add the installed HDP version to that file like this:

```
-Dhdp.version=2.2.0.0-2041 (your installed HDP version)
```

To figure out which hdp version is installed, please run this command in the cluster:

```
hdp-select status hadoop-client
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue:

```
launch_container.sh: line 24: $PWD:$PWD/__hadoop_conf__:$PWD/__spark__.jar:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*::$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure: bad substitution
```

As I couldn't find any /usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo* file, I just edited mapred-site.xml and removed 
"/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:"

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the ambari-yarn.

click on Configs->Advanced->Custom yarn-site->Add Property ...

add hdp version as key and value as your HDP version.
You will get hdp version along with below command

*hdp-select versions*

e.g. 2.5.3.0-37

Now add you property as

hdp.version=2.5.3.0-37

2. Otherwise replace ${hdp.version} as your hdp version(2.5.3.0-37) in yarn-site.xml and yarn-env.sh

Answer (score 1):

I also had this Issue using BigInsights 4.2.0.0 with yarn, spark and mapreduce 2 and what was causing it was the iop.version.
To fix it you have to add the iop.version variable to mapred-site, and this can be done into with the following steps:

In Ambari Server go to:

- MAPREDUCE2
- Configs (tab)
- Advanced (tab)
- Click into Custom mapred-site
- Add Property...
- Put iop.version and your BigInsights version.
- Restart all services.

This has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by `/bin/sh` linked to dash, instead of bash, which often happens on Debian based systems.

To fix it, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` and select no.

Comment: This is centos and it is bash; $ ll /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep  1 05:48 /bin/sh -> bash